# Private destructor yet I can manually delete the object in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Is there something wrong with VS2015 compiler? I always assumed that if I declare destructor of a class a private/protected I won't be able to manually destroy that object, yet in VS2015 I can easily compile that code:

```
class X
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T* create(T v = T{})
    {
        return new T{ v };
    }
    X(){}
private:
    ~X() {}

};

int main()
{
    X* x{new X};
    auto i{ x->create<int>() };
    auto d{ x->create<double>(2) };
    delete i;
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you don't manually destroy the object anywhere in your code... Did you mean to have a `delete x;` in there somewhere?

Comment: Add `delete x;` to see the problem.

Comment: @RSahu F me, of course! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program you do not call the destructor of the class X. If you write expression

```
delete x;
```

the program will not compile.

Consider a more simplified example

```
class X
{
    ~X() {}
};    


int main()
{
    X x;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will not compile the program because the destructor of the class is private and it shall be called at the end of main.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `x->create` method to create an `int` and a `double`, and then delete them.

`int` and `double` don't have destructors; there is no reason you cannot delete them.

`x` has a private destructor, but you do not delete x anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your X class is a templated factory class. It creates objects of type T, in your case an int* and a double*.

You then initialize an int* and double* pointers to the values returned by the factory, meaning the 2 new objects, on which you the call delete.

You never call delete on x itself, you call delete on objects returned by x::create (meaning i and d).